# Custom Cell in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have this collection view cell and I need to customize the cell. I know that the implementation is similar to UITableView, but I am not really sure what I can do customize this cell? Help would be greatly appreciated. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as UITableView, you can set a fully custom view, with right size. So think that it can have UIView, UILabel, and so on...This is not exactly a question, but think that you can do everything you do in a custom tableview cell.